# Digit only TextField with a unique decimal point in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I could develop the following code in Javascript that allows only digits to a given HTML `TextField`.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<input type='text' id='textField' name='textField' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">
```

but I need to allow *one and only one* decimal point (**.**) to be entered to the `TextField`. I tried some way but I didn't fabricate the code that could suite this requirement. How can I allow only digits along with a **unique** decimal point to a given `TextField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try out this Javascript? It works in my case:

```
var decimalPointCount = 0; 
        function checkInputData(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                if (charCode == 46 && decimalPointCount == 0) {
                    decimalPointCount++;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function isNumberKey(evt)
   {
 var charCode;
 if(evt.keyCode) //For IE
   charCode = evt.keyCode;
 else if(evt.Which)
   charCode = evt.Which; // For FireFox
 else
   charCode = evt.charCode; // Other Browser

     //var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
     return (charCode<=31 ||  charCode==46 || (charCode>=48 && charCode<=57));
   }

   function validCurrency(txt)
   {
      return txt.match(/^\d*(.\d{0,2})?$/);
   }

   function validateForm(formObj)
   {
     if(!validCurrency(document.getElementById('textField').value))
     {
       document.getElementById('textField').select();
       document.getElementById('textField').focus();
       return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
</script>

<form name="form1" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    Amount: <input type='text' id='textField' name='textField' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

it will allow only digits along with a unique decimal point.

Comment: It allows multiple decimal points to be entered. The decimal point must not be repeated and it must not be the first character and it is not working on Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Hi Lion, In IE and Chrome, event is resolving to window.event. Firefox doesn't have this property. This is the reason not working on Firefox. I will try with javascript.

Comment: hi now check with edited script. need to do first place decimal point check.