# enter one decimal point only in textbox html

Tags: javascript, html

I found many links regarding this question but none answers the problem correctly(completely).
How to restrict user to allow only one decimal point in textbox. 1.3 , 5.6 etc (user cannot enter two decimals) . And also user should not be able to copy paste other invalid data to the text field.? How to achieve this in javascript or jquery??

Comment: Please post your code so far and a demo to reproduce specific problem you have.

Comment: how many numbers before decimal?

Comment: A hint for you ... split a string with respect to dot(.) , then the array you get should be of length 2 in case of a single decimal point... you can use this info.... to code

Comment: two digits before decimal and one digit after decimal @Terror.Blade

Comment: possible duplicate of [Digit only TextField with a unique decimal point in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880942/digit-only-textfield-with-a-unique-decimal-point-in-javascript)

Comment: There are several previous questions about this. Spawning new copies of essentially the same question is not constructive. Search for the existing question that has the most promising answer(s) and contribute to improving the answer(s) by explaining why they are not satisfactory. At the very least, if you post a new copy of the question, show your best try so far, or the best solution you have found, and explain what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need javascript for that, use the HTML5 pattern attribute for an input:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required pattern="[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+">
</form>
```

As soon as you try to submit the form, the browser should show an error message. In older browsers you can [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-forms) this non-existent functionality.

Comment: It worked in firefox. But not sure whether it will work in all browsers and all versions. (Forget IE .However nothing works in IE :)

Comment: It only works in IE 8.0+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms, however that's what the linked polyfills for! Have a look at the list of html5 form polyfills, you can fill the gap for < IE 8.0

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very late reply for this question but since there is no satisfactory answer provided here, I will share my solution for future references.

you can add this function to your javascript file which will allow only one decimal point in that specific textbox input:

```js
function oneDecimalOnly(element) {

  var charCodeEnteredEntered = (event.which) ? event.which :
    (window.event.keyCode) ? window.event.keyCode : -1;

  // '.' decimal point  
  if (charCodeEnteredEntered === 46) {

    // Allow only 1 decimal point
    if ((element.value) && (element.value.indexOf('.') >= 0))
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="decimal" id="decimal" onkeypress="return oneDecimalOnly(this);">
</form>
```

I hope this will do fine. For more information visit http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/allow-only-numeric-values-and-allow-only-one-dot-in-textbox-using-javascript1, I found it very helpful.

Comment: This doesn't allow to enter number

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: Formance.js
github: https://github.com/omarshammas/jquery.formance